# How to split a string into individual lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How can you separate a JavaScript string into individual lines? I am thinking some innovative use of the `string.split(" ");` function, but can't see how it would work.

I can think of doing something like this - but it's a bit messy.

```
var Array = [];

var content = originalString.split(' ');
var i = 0;
var line = '';
do {
    do {
       var char = content[i];
       line = line + char;
       i++;
    } while (char !== '\n')
    Array.push(line);
} while (i <= content.length);
// for each line in Array, join to string. Type thing
```

Can you think of a neater / more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: can you not just do a string.replace(' ', '\n') ?

Comment: I would strongly encourage you not to have a variable called `Array`, as it will shadow the default global `Array` function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeh thanks it was just for question purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` can accept a regular expression, so:

```
var result = originalString.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
```

That allows for `\r\n` separators between lines (Windows), `\r` separators between lines (old Mac OS), and `\n` separators between lines (*nix, OS X).

Example:

```js
var originalString =
    "testing\none\r\ntwo\rthree\r\ntesting";
var result = originalString.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
console.log(result);
```